# Does enabling the cinemachine confiner 2D component forces the vcm to stick to 0 position of the game and not follow the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have created different regions in my game each having its own confiner for better player experience. Now I wrote a script that when the player passes through these triggers which I have set up will change the bounding shape of the 'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' component. The bounding shape is changing as it should, but the camera is stuck at position (0f, 0f, 0f) rather than following the player.

When disabling the 'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' before play testing, the vcm is following the player as intended.

'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' component enabled in the inspector

[image: 'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' component enabled in the inspector]

'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' component disabled in the inspector

[image: 'Cinemachine Confiner 2D' component disabled in the inspector]

```
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ConfinerChanging : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] CinemachineVirtualCamera playerFollowCamera;
    private CinemachineConfiner2D boundingConfiner;

    // Create a dictionary to map region tags to their colliders
    private Dictionary<string, PolygonCollider2D> regionColliders = new Dictionary<string, PolygonCollider2D>();

    private void Start()
    {
        boundingConfiner = playerFollowCamera.GetComponent<CinemachineConfiner2D>();

        // Populate the dictionary with regions by finding objects with PolygonCollider2D components and tags
        PolygonCollider2D[] collidersInScene = FindObjectsOfType<PolygonCollider2D>();
        foreach (PolygonCollider2D collider in collidersInScene)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collider.gameObject.tag))
            {
                regionColliders[collider.gameObject.tag] = collider;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        string regionTag = other.gameObject.tag;

        // Check if the region tag exists in the dictionary
        if (regionColliders.ContainsKey(regionTag))
        {
            Debug.Log("Entered " + regionTag);
            boundingConfiner.m_BoundingShape2D = regionColliders[regionTag];
        }
    }
}
```

above is the confiner changing script, it looks for all the polygon colliders in the game and adds them to the dictionary and when the player passes through any the bounding shape is then set the current collider.